# Multiple Google analytics Access code generated by Signin button

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to query Google Analytics data for the first time using their API and was having difficulty with the Google Sign in page. I got the Java script code from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/.

Everything is working fine except once the user signs in the Google sign-in button doesn't change. It gives the impression to the user that he/she can click on it again. When clicked on it again, the Google java script code generates another Authorization code and it keeps doing it every time it is clicked.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't the button detect not to re-execute the code? Or is this something I need to explicitly handle in java script?
Thanks.